# How do you make a discord bot that creates 'ghost' accounts?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've seen some bots that create 'ghost' accounts for representing a user, its still the same bot, clicking on a previous iteration shows the name and profile picture of the current iteration, but it never shows info about the user, as if they were deleted or left the server.

This is an example, this bot renames itself according to the user talking, its a chat log basically.
[image: Example]

In the picture I clicked on the 2nd user and as you can see it's the user most recently used.
The original bot never changes its name or anything when this happens, its literally like a new account.

I can't find *anything* on this subject, yet people just somehow know how to make this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "ghost accounts" are called [webhooks](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks). You can manually create webhooks (Server Settings > Webhooks > Create Webook) or by using [TextChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel)'s [.createWebhook(name, [avatar], [reason])](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createWebhook) method. Example:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content == "createWebhook") {
        message.channel.createWebhook("My Webhook", "https://support.discordapp.com/system/photos/3602/4079/7511/dan.png", "Reason").then(() => {message.reply("Webhook created!")}).catch((error) => {message.reply("Couldn't create webhook."); return console.log(error)});
    }
});

bot.login("TOKEN");
```

Using the webhook:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content == "sendWebhook") {
        const Webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient("Webhook ID", "Webhook Token");
        Webhook.send("Hello there!");
    }
});

bot.login("TOKEN");
```

You may, as well, use it in a HTML formular.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Send Webhook</title>
    </head>
    <body class = "bg-dark">
        <main class = "container">
            <div class = "card">
                <div class = "card-header text-center">Send Webhook</div>
                <div class = "card-body">
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <form id = "form">
                            <label for = "url">Webhook URL: *</label>
                            <input required type = "text" id = "url" class = "form-control">

                            <label for = "message">Webhook Message: *</label>
                            <input required type = "text" id = "message" class = "form-control">

                            <hr>

                            <label for = "username">Webhook Username:</label>
                            <input type = "text" id = "username" class = "form-control">

                            <label for = "avatar">Webhook Avatar:</label>
                           <input type = "text" id = "avatar" class = "form-control">

                           <hr>

                            <div class = "d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#form").submit(function() {
                    var url = $("#url").val();
                    var message = $("#message").val();
                    var username = $("#username").val();
                    var avatar = $("#avatar").val();

                    $.post(url, {"content": message, "username": username, "avatar_url": avatar})
                    return false;
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```